# Blazor WebView CurrentInputLanguage

Tags: c#, blazor, webview2

I have an application based on WebView2 and BlazorWebView hosted inside an WPF application and experiencing an strange problem where setting InputLanguageManager.Current.CurrentInputLanguage from an EventCallback does not change input language. When executing exactly same code within Button event handler works as expected.

I have tried invoking the changed on current dispatcher but still once the function completes the current language is reverted to Invariant Culture. So it looks like that the change only affects calling thread.

```
public async Task SetCurrentLanguageAsync(CultureInfo inputLanguage)
{
   await Application.Current?.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => 
       InputLanguageManager.Current.CurrentInputLanguage = inputLanguage);
}

public void SetCurrentLanguage(CultureInfo inputLanguage)
{
    Application.Current?.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        InputLanguageManager.Current.CurrentInputLanguage = inputLanguage);
}
```

Anyone can provide any info on why this could be happening?
Thanks!